# @Html.DropDownList how to set default value be ACTIVE

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to default value for my drop down be Active instead of Inactive.

I have tried "Selected=true" for active but ,my dropdwon always shows Incative is selected

```
<div class="form-group input-group-lg">
  <label>Status</label><br />
   @Html.DropDownList("Status", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text="Active", Value = "True",Selected=true  }, new SelectListItem { Text="Inactive", Value = "False"} }, "Select The Status..") 
  <br />
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the third Parameter as a default value.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Status", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text="Active", Value = "True",Selected=true  }, Model.SomeDefaultValue, "Select The Status..")
```

The Good Way to Create a ViewModel and Include all the data to that viewModel and render it like this.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Status", Model.ListOfSomeThing, Model.SomeDefaultValue, "Select The Status..")
```

(This would be more Cleaner.)

I hope it helps!

> **Example:**

**ViewModel**

```
 public class SimpleViewModel{
     public List<SelectListItem> Status_List {get; set}
     public string Default_Status {get; set}

     public SimpleViewModel(){
         CustomerList  = new List<SelectListItem>();
         Default_Status= "Active"; //default value.
}
```

**Action Method**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   SimpleViewModel viewModel = new SimpleViewModel();
   viewModel.Status_List = // Initialize it here.
   viewModel.Default_Status = // If you want to Change you Default_Status.

   return view(viewModel);
}
```

**View**

```
   @Html.DropDownList("Customer", Model.CustomerList, Model.Customer)
```

Comment: What should be some default value.please suggest me.

Comment: My status is in boolen .But in this example customer is in string ,please suggest me how to handle it

Comment: You welcome. @Manish .. if you don't mind please mark at as a answer (Thanks for that in advance).

Answer (score 0):

This code looks fine, and when I tried this code I got Active as default selected value.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it in the Controller:

```
private void SetSelectListItem(string currency = null)
{
    ViewBag.Currencies = _currencyService.GetAllCurrencies().Select(x =>
                          new SelectListItem
                          {
                              Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                              Text = x.Name,
                              Selected = x.Id.ToString() == currency
                          }).ToList();
}
```

and in my view, use **DropDownListFor**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Currency, ViewBag.Currencies, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%" })
```